# Mask input field for Zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Looking to mask the input field, along the lines of what this jQuery plugin does:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

I tried converting it to Zepto by changing:

```
$.fn.extend({
```

to

```
$.extend({
```

and

```
})(jQuery);
```

to

```
})(Zepto);
```

Now I'm getting: Object # has no method 'mask' 
and not sure where to go from there.

Is there any other input masking plugin I can use with Zepto or something I'm missing on converting this to Zepto?

Comment: Why do you change `$.fn.extend` to `$.extend` - don't you want to extend the prototype?

Comment: zepto requires it to be different

Comment: OK, changing it *and* applying it on the prototype (as in your answer) makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jquery the to make a plugin goes as follows:

```
$.fn.extend({
```

Zepto needs to be

```
$.extend($.fn,{
```

Works perfect now.